# Custom key function for python defaultdict

Tags: python, dictionary

What is a good way to define a custom key *function* analogous to the `key` argument to `list.sort`, for use in a `collections.defaultdict`?

Here's an example use case:

```
import collections

class Path(object):
    def __init__(self, start, end, *other_features):
        self._first = start
        self._last = end
        self._rest = other_features
    def startpoint(self):
        return self._first
    def endpoint(self):
        return self._last
    # Maybe it has __eq__ and __hash__, maybe not

paths = [... a list of Path objects ...]

by_endpoint = collections.defaultdict(list)
for p in paths:
    by_last_name[p.endpoint()].append(p)
# do stuff that depends on lumping paths with the same endpoint together
```

What I desire is a way to tell `by_endpoint` to use `Path.endpoint` as the `key` function, similar to the `key` argument to `list.sort`, and not have to put this key definition into the `Path` class itself (via `__eq__` and `__hash__`), since it is just as sensible to also support "lumping by start point" as well.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with `defaultdict`? Sounds like you want to be able to hash an object based on attributes of the object rather than the object's own default equality and hashing rules? That is, you want to be able to say `by_last_name[p]` and have it seamlessly hash and compare based on the results of a call to `p.last_name()`, is that right? Or maybe just call `p.last_name()` and store that as the key, not storing `p` as the key at all?

Comment: But the last name **is** part of the definition of a person. A group of persons could be a hash of people by last name, but that's not a person.

Comment: @ShadowRanger There might be approaches that don't depend on `defaultdict` however, I tried to provide the specific case that I'm dealing with: making a `defaultdict` that "lumps together" instances of a class by a subset of their properties w/o embedding this feature into the class itself.

Comment: As an aside, you might be interested in looking at [PEP 455](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0455/) (it was rejected, though)

Comment: @Dave: Seems like what you have is already correct though. It wouldn't be sane to store `p` itself as the key since many non-equal keys would be treated as colliding, and implicitly calling `last_name` on all keys and storing that as the key is spooky action at a distance; implicit behaviors like that generally violate the Zen of Python (Explicit is better than Implicit). It would also be really weird to require people who want to find all people with a given last name to make a fake Person with that last name just to perform the lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class defaultkeydict(defaultdict):

    def __init__(self, default_factory, key=lambda x: x, *args, **kwargs):
        defaultdict.__init__(self, default_factory, *args, **kwargs)
        self.key_func = key

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return defaultdict.__getitem__(self, self.get_key(key))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        defaultdict.__setitem__(self, self.get_key(key), value)

    def get_key(self, key):
        try:
            return self.key_func(key)
        except Exception:
            return key
```

Note the logic that falls back to the passed-in key if the key function can't be executed. That way you can still access the items using strings or whatever keys.

Now:

```
p = Path("Seattle", "Boston")
d = defaultkeydict(list, key=lambda x: x.endpoint())
d[p].append(p)
print(d)      # defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Boston': [<__main__.Path object at ...>]})
```

Comment: This is not helpful to me because it involves putting functionality, `__key__`, into the class.  I'm trying to avoid this.

Comment: Rewrote to put the logic in the container rather than the contained objects.